# Welcome file javascript import

Tags: css, jsp

Currently, I have a jsp file that I am redirecting to from index.jsp to jsp/home.jsp
The import is something like this.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
```

the location of the above file is

`webcontent/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css`

However, if I try to click on a link to jsp/signIn.jsp, I get file not found on the css file.

I am not sure why home.jsp is behaving like it is in webcontent folder when it is in webcontent/jsp

Is there a way to work around the issue?

Comment: what is the location of `jsp/signIn.jsp` relative to `webcontent/` directory ?

Comment: the path would be webcontent/jsp/signIn.jsp

Comment: and is the link `<link rel` in the `jsp` file ?

Comment: yes it is in the jsp file

Comment: also, the other files such as images behave like the file is in webcontent folder as supposed to the webcontent/jsp folder. so should i change something so that the home.jsp file behaves the way it is supposed to? like it is located in webcontent/jsp?

Comment: yeah.. you could try that.. remove `../` and see

Comment: i could remove that and it would work. but the other files such as the signIn.jsp, which is located in the same folder webcontent/jsp/signIn.jsp does not behave the same way.

Comment: that is the wierdest thing i have seen :)

Comment: which is why the question ended up in stackoverflow :) so something I should do to have the home.jsp behave like it is in webcontent/jsp where it originally is as supposed to webcontent?

Comment: i have the imports in another file imports.jsp and using jsp:incude to put it into home.jsp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (with JSTL tag):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<c:url value="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"/>">
```

Comment: That worked. I remembered this from my last work but somehow slipped my mind. Thank you for the input

Answer (score 0):

Got around the problem. Had to use the context path as supposed to using the relative path. 
I didnt need to deal with having the behaviour of the file at all.
Guess thats the answer.

**Use Context Path!!**